# java.util.InputMismatchException when reading simple value

Tags: java, exception, io, java.util.scanner

I had read similar answers here, but still I can't think what's going on here. I've got the following snippet:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String text = null;
    int option, value = 0;

    System.out.println("1. Cipher - 2. Decypher");
    option = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            text = scanner.nextLine();
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            break;

        case 2:
            text = scanner.nextLine();
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("you have entered " + text);
    System.out.println("you have entered " + value);
}
```

So if you enter 1, you can write a String, then an int. Simple, right?

Then, why am I getting this output after typing "1", enter and then "hello"?

```
1. Cipher - 2. Decypher
1
hello
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at phd.cml.PruBorrar.main(PruBorrar.java:19)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanner.nextInt() method only returns the next int, it doesn't consume the newline you are entering after the int.

The nextLine() call will then consume the newline after the int:

```
text = scanner.nextLine();
```

And then this will attempt to consume "hello" and throw an InputMismatchException:

```
value = scanner.nextInt();
```

So basically you just have to add an extra `scanner.nextLine()` after the call to `scanner.nextInt()`

This explains it more thoroughly: https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/wiki/scanner